# How do I reference multiple-word categories in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

If I have a category called "Featured Article" in Jekyll, how do I reference that within a loop?  I'm essentially trying to do this:

```
{% for post in site.categories['Featured Article'] %}
```

In the end I changed my category name to just "featured", and was able to get what I need with:

```
{% for post in site.categories.featured %}
```

However, I'd like to know what the syntax would be for when it's not an option to change the category name.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the category name to lower case when using it in templates:

```
{% for post in site.categories['featured article'] %}
```

[Jekyll stores categories in lower case internally](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/v2.5.1/lib/jekyll/post.rb#L83). This behavior may change when [this pull request](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/2571) is resolved.